# PhpStorm Autocomplete for Tailwind CSS not working

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, tailwind-css, nuxtjs

I currently have a NuxtJS (VueJS) project with Tailwind in it (latest versions).
I am using PhpStorm as editor.

For some reason I have no auto completion of suggestion for Tailwind CSS.
I have tried a lot of different things (anything I found on Google) but so far nothing helped.

Can anyone help me to find out what is wrong and how to fix this?

Latest thing I tried was a `npm ci` and **Invalidate Caches/ Restart** in PhpStorm but that did not help unfortunately.

I am using the latest version of PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `"jit"` mode? With it, code completion list is very limited, most of applicable CSS classes are not suggested. This will be fixed in the scope of [WEB-50318](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50318), please follow it for updates.

Note also that, when using latest `tailwindcss` versions, the completion includes unrelated CSS classes from some `*.test.css` files. This will be fixed with the next tailwindcss package update, see https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4393. Workaround: delete `node_modules/tailwindcss/jit/tests/` folder, it's not needed.

Comment: Yeah I have "jit" mode activated at the moment, but to be honest, auto completion has been working for 3 ~ 4 days and all the sudden it stopped. I will try disabling JIT and see if that helps. Thank you both for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem with WebStorm and the previous answer diddnt solve my issue. However, I was able to solve it by instead of using `mode: 'jit'` in my tailwind config, by adding the `--jit` compiler option. Restart WebStorm afterwards.

Comment: Do you have an example of where to put `--jit`

Comment: When using the tailwind build cli. `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch --jit`